# Aggregate data, create new column that counts number of repeated strings, R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an array called mydata.  The column titles are c("name","ID","Stuff_A","Stuff_B").  "name" is a string, "ID" is a number attributed to each "name", and "Stuff_A" and "Stuff_B" are just numerical values that I want to sum.  If I use,

aggregate(.~ID+name,mydata,sum)

I get what I almost want.  "Stuff_A" and "Stuff_B" are summed for values with the same name name and ID.  However, I would also like to create a new column in the aggregated data that tells me how many instances of each name were found.  Any ideas?

Edit:  I meant that the column Stuff_A is summed together and the same for Stuff_B for each corresponding name.  Sorry.  Here is some data.

```
a = c(2, 3, 5, 4, 11, 6) 
s = c("A. Sphere", "A. Square", "A. Line", "A. Square","A. Sphere", "A. Square") 
e = c(1111,1112,1113,1112,1111,1112)
b = c(1, 8, 2, 0, 8, 1) 
df = data.frame(s,e, a, b)
colnames(df)<-c("name","id","Stuff_A","Stuff_B")
sumdf<-aggregate(.~name+id,df,sum)
```

The last line does almost what I want it to do but I would like a 5th column which has how many times each name showed up.  So in the case of the mock data I have here we would have 2 next to A. Sphere, 3 next to A. Square, and 1 next to A. Line.

Edit 2:  I did find a silly way around it.  I just created a new column prior to the aggregate command that copies the names column, renamed the new names column name_count, and the ran the aggregate command as is.  That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using library `dplyr` you can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name, id) %>% summarise(sumOfStuffA = sum(Stuff_A), sumOfStuffB = sum(Stuff_B), nObservations = n())
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
Groups: name [?]

       name    id sumOfStuffA sumOfStuffB nObservations
     (fctr) (dbl)       (dbl)       (dbl)         (int)
1   A. Line  1113           5           2             1
2 A. Sphere  1111          13           9             2
3 A. Square  1112          13           9             3
```

Comment: I added some mock data and cleared up what I wanted. Sorry I wasn't clear at all in my initial post.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer and also provided the output.

Comment: Best way to appreciate and thank on SO is to up vote or accept the answer. :)

Comment: I clicked the green check but I am too new to up vote

Comment: Came back to upvote this now that I am not so new.  LOL